# Aplicar Async/Await

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, async-await

Trabajo con Visual Studio 2019, ASP.NET Core 3.1

En la línea que aplico `await`, me da el siguiente error: "El operador `await` solo se puede usar dentro de una expresión lambda asincrónico"

```
public async Task AsignarIdentificaciones(Comprobante comprobante, List<TipoIdentificacion> identificaciones)
    {
        using (var context = new CatalogoInquilinoContext())
        {
            context.Entry(comprobante).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

            if (comprobante.TipoIdentificaciones == null)
                comprobante.TipoIdentificaciones = new List<TipoIdentificacion>();

            //Recorremos cada Modelo que se quiera asociar
            identificaciones.ForEach(x =>
            {
                //El Modelo tampoco debe recibir cambios
                context.Entry(x).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                //Asociamos a la coleción de Modelo del Proveedor el nuevo item
                //Este si recibira cambios
                comprobante.TipoIdentificaciones.Add(x);
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            });
        }
    }
```

¿Como puedo aplicar asyn/await a este método?

Saludos!

Comment: te falta un async dentro de la lambda

Comment: @fredyfx la parte de antes del `ForEach` puede ser de la siguiente manera `await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    context.Entry(comprobante).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                });`

Comment: solo tengo una pregunta a ello: ¿Por qué?

Comment: Me faltaría otro await porque el método da un mensaje se ejecutara como sincrónica, me refiero al código postiado antes del ForEach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método ForEach también debe ser asíncrono

```
//Recorremos cada Modelo que se quiera asociar
identificaciones.ForEach(async x =>
{
    //El Modelo tampoco debe recibir cambios
    context.Entry(x).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
    //Asociamos a la coleción de Modelo del Proveedor el nuevo item
    //Este si recibira cambios
    comprobante.TipoIdentificaciones.Add(x);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
});
```

Comment: Bien jugado bro :D

Comment: Me faltaría otro await porque el método da un mensaje se ejecutara como sincrónica, me refiero al código postiado antes del `ForEach`

Comment: utiliza el ForEachAsync https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.foreachasync?view=efcore-2.0